# How to get the ./configure parameters after installation

Tags: makefile, gnu-toolchain

Suppose I have compiled and installed some software package with:

```
./configure --with --some --parameters
make
make install
```

Is there any way I can get the parameters I passed to `./configure`?

I still have the original directory where `./configure` and `make` took place, but I am also interested in the other case, one where these files are no longer available.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

`configure.log` will have the arguments used when it was invoked at the very top of the file, `head configure.log` should be enough to view them.